# Python3 + Django . Cyrillic text unicode error

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, unicode

Please help with problem which might be typical for python2->3 switchers but still not clear how to solve. Using python 3.4 + django 1.8.Ajax function sends text as key for search to django, but when it's cyrrylic text the whole thing doesn't work. No error is shown. As far as I understand it's up to python3 handling unicode 'features'. Print function prints correct text to the console, when it's cyrillic output of relevant event objects is just empty(but there must be results for sure). When it's latin works fine

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def live_search(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
                key = request.data['key']
                result = Event.objects.filter(title__istartswith=key)
                events = serializers.serialize('json', result)
                print (key)
                print (result)
        data = {
                'events': events,

        }
        return Response(data)
```

How to fix it?

```
            key = request.data['key'].decode("ascii").encode('utf-8')
```

Leads to 500 error

EDIT:  Tried also 2.7 - same error. Empty output when search key is cyrillic . Both on localhost and in production

Comment: If this is a DRF API view, why are you using the plain Django serializer instead of the DRF ones?

Comment: `decode()`, `encode()`, `unicode()` functions?

Comment: @DanielRoseman djangorestframewor was recommended as the best way to implement few ajax things. but if there are only some functions, implementing basic things like live search, it doesn't really matter I suggested. I mean otherwise it would be required to create separate serliazers.py file

Comment: @sepulchered tried, and that leads to internal server error 500. the very error is not listed as far it's ajax request

Comment: why do you think it's in `ascii` encoding?

Comment: @sepulchered likely not. also tried one of cyrillic encodings .decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8'). print function prints normally so I guess it's not

Comment: @Vinand if you haven't updated it in settings, it should be `utf-8` or `unicode` by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143152/discussion-between-sepulchered-and-vinand).

Comment: @sepulchered b'\xd0\xbf' it's result of decoding to utf-8